# Removing or deleting variables in IPython

Tags: python, variables, ipython

Is there any command in IPython which clears all the variables in a workspace (releasing them from system memory) like in Matlab "clear"? I know only **del** command. **del** and name of the variable. But I want to remove all the variables in one go.

Comment: This is rarely a concern in scripts, and interactive native python sessions rarely grow that large. Are you using ipython or jupyter? They have a `%reset` magic. Or are you using spyder?

Comment: @AndrasDeak ipyhton

Comment: @Carcigenicate What I want to do is: Every time I run my script the previous variables should be deleted

Answer (score 0):

IPython supports the [`%reset`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-reset) magic that resets all names in the kernel.

However the way the python import mechanism works this can still lead to surprising behaviour if you modify a module and then expect the modified code to be reloaded after `%reset` when you import it again. I haven't tried this for a long time but if memory serves, the module doesn't actually get re-imported (a'la [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)), beause this is how python's import system behaves anyway.

So in case you are modifying modules on the fly, it's best to just restart the whole session anyway. The history will still be there, and you're not going to use names defined earlier anyway.